# How can I add the number and its reverse in Python?

Tags: python

I have to add a number and its reverse without using functions or strings.
This is my code:

```
number = int(input("Enter your number: "))
revs_number = 0
while (number > 0):   
    remainder = number % 10  
    revs_number = (revs_number * 10) + remainder  
    number = number // 10

print("The reverse number is ", revs_number)
print(number + revs_number)
```

When I run this, the output is:

```
Enter your number: 56
The reverse number is 65
65
```

I tried everything I know but I couldn't add these two. I searched this forum too, couldn't find any solution without strings and functions. Can someone help me please? I really want to learn how because this took my time! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `number` is beeing changed in the loop. Save number in another variable and add this to the `revs_number`

Comment: You should add 'print debugging' to `everything I know`. You could have found out what is going wrong with something as simple as: `print(number)` as your last line.

Comment: thank you Exciter!! and quamrana, i just started learning this, and thanks to you i added print debugging to my brain :)

Comment: Also, anticipating that you keep learning python, here is the mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: i will check that out definitely. thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

`Number` is 0 at the end of the `while` loop, you need to store it in a temporary variable

```
number = int(input("Enter your number: "))
revs_number = 0
tmp = number

while (tmp > 0):
    remainder = tmp % 10
    revs_number = (revs_number * 10) + remainder
    tmp = tmp // 10

print("The reverse number is ", revs_number)
print(number + revs_number)
```

Comment: thank you so much!! i can't believe it was this easy... i need to study more i guess

Answer (score 0):

```py
number = int(input("Enter your number: "))
revs_number = 0
initial_num=number #copy your input, after while loop execution it will be 0

while (number > 0):   
    remainder = number % 10  
    revs_number = (revs_number * 10) + remainder  
    number = number // 10

print(number) #output 0
print("The reverse number is ", revs_number)
print(initial_num + revs_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `number` is being modified in the loop. Assigning this to a new variable would solve this issue like here:

```
user_input = int(input("Enter your number: "))
number = user_input

revs_number = 0
while (number > 0):   
    remainder = number % 10  
    revs_number = (revs_number * 10) + remainder  
    number = number // 10

print("The reverse number is ", revs_number)
print(user_input + revs_number)
```

Hope this helps!